# My EBS volume (attached to live instance) and all snap shots vanished

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Yesterday I had a nightmarish experience with my AWS account.

In short:‎
‎1.‎    My only running instance was taken out of service in response to an EC2 instance status checks ‎failure at 2021-09-23T19:00:46Z. ‎
‎2.‎    A new instance was started in response to a difference between desired and actual capacity, ‎increasing the capacity from 0 to 1 at 2021-09-23T19:01:06Z.‎
‎3.‎    Volume attached to my running instance was gone along with all data, software etc. nowhere ‎to be found.‎
‎4.‎    All the weekly snap shots of this volume are also gone, so I cannot recreate volume.

‎
I am using AWS services for many many years and it never happened to me. I am very surprised that this can happen on AWS.‎

I have posted the question on AWS EC2 discussion forum. But I noticed that they rarely answer any question.

Should I buy there "Developer Support" for $29 per month but I am not sure even that will solve the problem. And how they will ensure that it does not happen again.

Any advice what should I do in this situation?

PS: Only now I realized the importance of good customer support when choosing cloud service provider.

Answer (score 2):

The message that *"A new instance was started in response to a difference between desired and actual capacity"* indicates that **you were using an Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling Group**.

Auto Scaling groups will automatically **launch new instances** when capacity is required and **terminate instances** when there is too much capacity. Also, if an instance fails health checks, it will be **automatically terminated** and replaced with a new instance.

When Auto Scaling terminates an instance, the EC2 instance is 'killed'. Any Amazon EBS volumes attached to the instance will, by default, also be deleted unless **Delete on Termination** is intentionally turned off.

When operating under an Auto Scaling group, **it is not a good idea to store data on the instance itself** because instances can be launched and terminated. Data should be stored in a database, or in Amazon S3 or Amazon EFS.

AWS *might* be able to recover that data if the volumes were recently deleted. Yes, you would need to subscribe to [AWS Support](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/plans/) to request assistance.

It is unfortunate that your instance was launched under Auto Scaling many years ago, which led to this problem. On the plus side, it shows the reliability of Amazon EC2 since was running without issue for all those years (until now).

Comment: Though I am pretty sure that I unselected "delete on termination" but I have no way to confirm. Further why all my snapshots are gone? On snapshot page I see "On snapshot page I see this message:‎
‎An error occurred fetching snapshot data: Exception caught: Index: -1, Size: 3
". What does this message means?

Comment: You are correct -- Snapshots should _not_ disappear. Make sure you are viewing the correct **Region** in the console (people sometimes get redirected to the wrong region in the console, which is why their resources seem to 'disappear'). Does that "Exception caught" message appear in the AWS management console, or are you calling an API?

Comment: Thanks John for your reply. I checked the region many times. Also checked global view to check if I have resources in any other region. This exception caught message is in console.

Comment: It is very unusual to see such errors in the console. Permission errors are often seen, but not 'exception' messages. Does it appear if you use a different browser? The error suggests to me that it is attempting to display 3 snapshots. You could also try the AWS CLI command `aws ec2 describe-snapshots` to see if they are there.

Comment: Ok I will post result after trying cli and changing browsers.

Comment: Inside CLI,  I ran the command <aws ec2 describe-snapshots --owner-ids xxxxxxxxxx> (my id) and get only one snapshot which I can also see in console. Still guessing what happened to other snapshots? Don't know where I went wrong. Has shaken my confidence on cloud system. Can I keep a local copy (on my computer) of volume or snapshot as backup?

Comment: No, it is not possible to download an Amazon EBS Snapshot. Please believe us when we say that things don't just disappear on their own -- there is always a reason. If the data was important to you, then try with AWS Support.

Comment: You are quit right John. I am going to contact AWS support. The more important thing than data is to know where I went wrong or something happened on AWS side. Thanks a lot for your help. At least I learned how to use CLI which I always dreaded :).